# PHP: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: php

I've just moved my hosting to GoDaddy, but I've stumbled upon a weird problem: Every single PHP page returns an error page with this message: "The system cannot find the path specified." There's no error code or description. I've tried looking into the source code of the error page but there's nothing as well.

Even the simplest page, like `<?php echo("Hello world"); ?>` returns the same error message.

However, HTML pages load regularly. What could be happening here?

Comment: Do you have `include()` files? Does your new directory layout match the old one?

Comment: Ask GoDaddy - they will help you.

Comment: How does the code of the page with "just hello word" looks like? Do you have an `include` statement somewhere?

Comment: No, like I said, if I upload a page with nothing but an echo("Hello world"), it still returns the same error.

Comment: The code for the Hello World page is simply:
`<?php
    echo("Hello world");
?>`

As far as asking GoDaddy for help, I already did it. They said it was FTP. Which makes no sense, since I'm using FTP regularly.

Comment: Do you have PHP enabled on the server?

Comment: I've triple checked it and it says it's enabled. So, yes.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problems. Call GoDaddy again and talk to a different CS rep. The code sample in your question should work, assuming it is actually on the server.

Comment: start fresh... delete all files and make sure to delete hidden files like the .htaccess. Then upload 1 php file with phpinfo().
I googled it and someuser had a similar problem... said it was the .htaccess file. does godaddy add one by default?

Comment: Did exactly that, Matt, but it didn't work. It isn't the .htaccess either...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the hosting is on iis ver 6 , just request change to iis 7. Next time you call mention this. Ill bet $10 its your problem

Comment: Already updated it to IIS 7. Not the problem either.

Comment: @user2005880  There goes my 10 bucks... have you tried reinstalling the default scripts directory?  http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4914/reinstalling-the-default-scripts-directory-on-windows-shared-hosting

Comment: I just did that, but now PHP is in this "Pending setup" status for the past 15 minutes. Is this normal?

Comment: @user2005880 I would say give it a minute but at this point i assume you have at this point :) whats the status on it now?